# invalid getelementptr indices

Tags: llvm

I'm getting "invalid getelementptr indices" on the last line of this llvm-IR code:

```
%alc = alloca %mytype*
store %mytype* %obj, %mytype** %alc
%ldc = load %mytype** %alc
%gcs = getelementptr inbounds %mytype* %ldc, i32 0, i32 1
```

where mytype is defined as follows:

```
%mytype = type {i32, %tp1**, %tp1}
```

I have another similar type that indexing over it doesn't cause the above error and is defined as:

```
%mytype2 = type {i32, i16*, %tp1}
```

Any help to resolve this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show a complete failing file, including the definition of `%tp1`, please? The GEP itself looks fine to me.

Comment: the failing file is so large that cannot be attached, but %tp1 is defined as follows: %tp1 = type {i32 (...)**, %tp2* (...)**, i1 (...)**, void (...)**, %tp1* (...)**}

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused because `%mytype` does not define a valid type. Normally LLVM reports an error on the type itself, but if the type definition appears later than a getelementptr (GEP) usage, then you only get an error from the GEP and not from the type.

If you move the definition of `%mytype` to appear before the GEP in the IR file you'll see a more appropriate error message.

In this case, I'm guessing the problem is that `%mytype` is incomplete - either the definition for `%tp1` is missing, or the definition to a type it uses (e.g. `%tp2`, which I see in your comment that it uses) is missing, or something like that.

By the way, you might want to use my [IR editor](http://amishne.github.com/llvm-ir-editor/), it would help you quickly find these sorts of errors.

Comment: thanks for your help, but it seams that this editor cannot be opened in eclipse Indego 3.7 and this error is given:           Could not open the editor: The editor class could not be instantiated. This usually indicates a missing no-arg constructor or that the editor's class name was mistyped in plugin.xml.

Comment: @user1723583 Bummer, I'll look into it ([opened a bug](https://github.com/amishne/llvm-ir-editor/issues/76)). Meanwhile you can just reverse the order and let LLVM itself report on the problem.

Comment: @user1723583 turns out I *don't* support Eclipse 3.7 out-of-the-box, there's [an extra (simple) step you need to take](http://amishne.github.io/llvm-ir-editor/#older_eclipse). Updated the FAQ and the installation prerequisites accordingly, and now it will no longer let you install if it can't find that dependency. Thanks for letting me know.